# flex, defined type, get data, grid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flex4

I have a data type defined like this and i want to use it in the flex4.6  dataGrid.

```
package data
{
    [Bindable]
    public class GridDataItem{
        protected var avatar:String;
        protected var name:String;
        protected var email:String;

        public function GridDataItem(avatar:String, name:String,email:String){
            this.avatar = avatar;
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
        }
    }
}
```

but i wondering how to reference one property in it.  beside this i also want to set the source picture which is saved as avatar in this datatype object, and the first column will display the avatar for each row .

anyone have any ideas ? thx million.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add public setters and getters within the class like below.

```
package data
{
    [Bindable]
    public class GridDataItem{
    protected var _avatar:String;
    protected var _name:String;
    protected var _email:String;

    public function GridDataItem(avatar:String, name:String,email:String){
        this.avatar = avatar;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public function set avatar(String av):void{
        this._avatar = av;
    }

    public function get avatar():String{
        return this._avatar;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

> beside this i also want to set the source picture which is saved as
>   avatar in this datatype object, and the first column will display the
>   avatar for each row

If I understood this question right, I'll set the url of the image in the avatar property of the griditem data type. Use [custom Item rendered](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-1c32bcb9124deadc3e9-8000.html) in the first column, use [Image](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Image.html) class within the itemrenderer to bind to this `avatar` property.

Comment: Thx for your information, although i still think flex is mess in some how, but i made what i want works. thanks again for your information.  cheers.